# Google maps android api won't work in release mode even though I specified package name and key's SHA-1 fingerprint in console

Tags: android, google-maps

I know this sounds like a repeated question, but I am searching for two days now and I am getting nowhere.
I am using Google maps android api v2 and it is working fine in debug mode. But when I sign it with a release key, the map won't load at all.
What I have done is that:

1 - I created a new project in the google developer console

2 - I Enabled google maps api

3 - I created a new api key using the "Credentials" menu

4 - I restricted it with the my SIGNING KEY's SHA-1 fingerprint and package name (and yes, I am pretty sure that they are correct)

5 - I added the key it gave me to my manifest file :

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="blablabla"/>
```

But it is still only working in debug mode (I added the debug SHA-1 fingerprint exactly the way I did it with the release key), and not with my release apks

I tried everything :

- regenerating the key
- as some suggested, the manifest file can bee in `src/debug` and I should put the key in `src/release`. But since I am using the newest version of android studio, there are no `release` or `debug` folders in `src`
- I tried creating a whole new project in google's developer console and it didn't work

I seriously don't know what else to do.

does anyone please have a suggestion?

ps: I am not getting any errors regarding the key being incorrect or something; The map won't just load. Even the little google logo won't appear at the bottom of the map

Comment: Are you using the same API key for both debug and release? Or are you using two API keys, one for debug and one for release?

Comment: I tried both methods but none worked. I mean once I created an api key and only added my release key signatures and it didn't work. I also created another key and added both the release and debug signatures, but it still only works in debug mode

Comment: Are you putting your API key in a `google_maps_api.xml` file? Or are you putting it directly in the manifest?

Comment: I am putting it directly in the manifest
since I started my project with a blank activity, no `google_maps_api.xml` file was created

Comment: How did you get the SHA1 fingerprint of your release key?

Comment: I am using windows. so in cmd I went to the location that my `key.jks` file is, and then typed: `keytool -list -v -keystore key.jks`
I then entered its password and from there I copy/pasted the SHA-1 signiture

Comment: Does your device/emulator have Internet access to check the API key?

Comment: If you mean that I have internet access on my device, yes I have. since I am calling some other web services to get to this map activity

Comment: Are you sure that you're using the correct keystore file? The one you're using to sign this app?  It sounds like it should be working....

Comment: I am using the same key. I am pretty sure. It should be working but it isn't. It is fraustrating

Comment: You have to generate both SHA1 and SHA256 fingerprints for both of the keys (debug and release) and add these into the console to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so for all people who like me, spent days trying to figure this same issue, I finally found out what the problem was.

As opposed to what I searched for the past three days, it actually CAN be a proguard problem. Almost all the suggestions throughout the internet (and google's own api documentation) were telling me that google's apis dont't need any special proguard rules when you obfuscate your release apk. But as it turns out (or at least in my case), it dose

here's the proguard rule I added to solve the problem (a subset of these rules niether the time nor motivation to test it after three days) :

```
#this alone won't slove the problem. but it is good to be here
-keep class com.google.android.gms.maps.** { *; }
-keep interface com.google.android.gms.maps.** { *; }

# I saw in their code that the api uses parcelables
-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    static *** CREATOR;
}

# I added this because of a suggestion I found on the internet
-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID;
    static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();
}

#to be safe, don't dare touch the google apis at all
-keep class com.google.** {
  public protected private *;
}
```

Comment: A noble effort, but this doesn't fix my problem.  I can run the app in debug mode perfectly, but building a release version (and then manually installing) still doesn't work, even with this heroic effort.  Sigh.

Answer (score 0):

@roostaamir its not work for me. finally i found solution please follow below link might be helpful [Google play app signing for this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46191310/7589424)