# Google maps not showing after uploading the app to playstore

Tags: android, api, google-maps, dictionary, keystore

Google maps showing a blank screen after uplaoding the app into playstore. But Map showing when running locally(in emulator).
I tried by changing the SHA1 of google map api by Playstore app signing certificate SHA fingerprint but still showing the blank screen.

Comment: make sure you have the right API key. :)

Comment: @AkhilNair API Key is correct.

Comment: did you genrated sha key with your release key?

Comment: Don't trust emulator when you are working with google maps. Try a real device and check whether it is working or not. Check if the binding is done properly. Debug step by step is it able to load the layout content.

Comment: @BhuvaneshBs How can i do that?

Comment: I am also faced same issue. The tricky is, goto playstore, in Release Management Section we have option like  App signing. In this you need to copy the SHA1 key and add the SHA1 key to your API Credentials.

Comment: @AkhilNair Its working with the real device when running locally. Not working when downloading from the playstore.

Comment: @N.V.Rao I have done the same, But still not working.

Comment: I wrote an article about this that may help: https://auri.net/2021/07/29/fix-app-no-longer-works-after-uploaded-to-google-play/

Answer (score 35, accepted):

*Please run the app first in real device and if it working then do as follow.*

> If u have enabled the App Signing Feature in the Developer Console,
>   then it's clearly written in the documentation that the Upload
>   Certificate is only needed by Google for authentication and that
>   upload certificate is removed before installing the application on the
>   user's phone. So, u also need to give the App Signing Certificate SHA
>   under the key which you have enabled for Google Maps API. The App
>   Signing Page is as I have attached the screenshot for your
>   convenience... In the image I have marked which you need to give as
>   additional credentials

[image]

Comment: I Copied SHA1 Certificate fingerprint to Google map api key,still not working

Comment: have you run app in real device? is it showing a map?

Comment: Its not showing map when i download the map from playstore, But When i run from android studio map is showing

Comment: @Bhuvanesh Bs Found release sha key and copied it in google maps api console, still not working.

Comment: Thanks Zafar, its working perfectly.  To whom its not working let me clarify.. when you create an api key for map in google dev console , you add package name and release sha 1 , after adding this you just need to add package name & SHA-1 from app signing key from App signing section in release management in google play console.

Answer (score 23):

Thanks for all the answers.

There are two google_maps_api.xml files in the app one for debug and another for release.

release :   app\src\release\res\values\google_maps_api.xml

debug : app\src\debug\res\values\google_maps_api.xml

In my case the api key was blank in release google_maps_api.xml

Comment: I want to hug you. Been struggling with this for hours.

Answer (score 2):

According to me the SHA1 keys are different for debug key and release key. But it will not work after upload on play store. To visible map you should follow the steps.
-  go to https://play.google.com/apps/publish/signup
    In that go release option. Copy SHA1 key from App signing certificate
-  Paste it while Editing API key which is generated for your app.
Note : Your API should present into both debug and release xml file.

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain a SHA1 key for release so easily.

in your **Gradle** enter your release key details like this.

```
signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("F:/Development/release_myapp.keystore")
            storePassword "231232das"
            keyAlias "myapp_rel"
            keyPassword "dasd333_das"
        }
    }
```

Then run **signingReport** in Gradle task:

[image]

You will get release SHA in run window.

If you've opted in for **Google Play App Signing Feature**, You have to another one SHA key to your console which is generated by google. Follow the Zoffa answer to get that.

[image]

For more info Source: http://devdeeds.com/create-sha1-key-using-android-studio/

Comment: Is the SHA1 differrent for debug and release?

Comment: Yes you have to use 2 sha keys. one for debug and one for release

Comment: That is the default but nothing stops you from signing your debug releases with your release key.  I do this to avoid having to deal with debug certificates which are unique to each device.

Comment: @Bhuvanesh Bs Should i copy the release sha key to google map api?